# get SharedPrefrences values in fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, sharedpreferences

how can i get SharedPrefrences value for example below get login status in fragment for save?

```
SharedPreferences prefs;
prefs= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("isSignIn", "Yes");
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

anyone who is confused i can give you a simple code :

// You can create separate class for sharedPreferences and use it in every activity

```
public class UserLoginPref {

private Context context;
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private String Phone;
private boolean isSignIn;

public void setIsSignIn(boolean isSignIn){
sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("isSignIn",isSignIn).commit();
}

public boolean getIsSignIn(){
isSignIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isSignIn",false);
}


public String getPhone() {
    String mobile = sharedPreferences.getString("Phone","");
    return mobile;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    sharedPreferences.edit().putString("Phone",phone).commit();
}

public UserLoginPref(Context context){
    this.context = context;
    sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("UserLoginPref",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

public void logOutUser(){
    sharedPreferences.edit().clear();
    setPhone("");
}
}




// And use it in your activity like this
UserLoginPref userPref = new UserLoginPref(this);
userPref.setIsSignIn(true);
```

Comment: ohhh im very interesting to use your code... thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

try to use `String result = prefs.getString("isSignIn", "No");`, some doc in [HERE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences#getString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). btw. it would be better to store `boolean` instead of `String`

Comment: thanks my friend i try this and tell you what happened !

Answer (score 1):

I have a manager file which I use in most of my projects. Below is the code for that.

```
class PreferenceManager constructor(
    private val context: Context
 ) {

private var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences =
    context.getSharedPreferences(context.packageName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

companion object {
    const val USER_ID = "user_id"
}


fun clearSharedPreferences(sessionExpired: Boolean) {
    context.getSharedPreferences(context.packageName, 0).edit().clear().apply()
    val preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
    preferences.edit().clear().apply()
}

fun saveBooleanValue(key: String, value: Boolean) {
    sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(key, value).apply()
}

fun getBooleanValue(key: String): Boolean {
    return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, false)
}

fun saveStringValue(key: String, value: String) {
    sharedPreferences.edit().putString(key, value).apply()
}

fun getStringValue(key: String): String? {
    return sharedPreferences.getString(key, null)
}

fun saveIntValue(key: String, value: Int) {
    sharedPreferences.edit().putInt(key, value).apply()
}

fun getIntValue(key: String): Int {
    return sharedPreferences.getInt(key, 0)
}
```

}

Above class has all getters and setter. Where ever you need to save data just call save method on Preference instance. And same for getting data. By this, you will have a center point to manager inserting and fetching data. In future you can add any type encryption in one central place and that is your preference class which I just shared. Furthermore, you will have central point to define keys in companion object. Any where from the project you will have access to this.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Initialize shared preferences
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("com.your.package", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

//Write the value to shared preferences
sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("isSignIn", true).apply();

//Get the value from shared preferences
sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isSignIn", default_value);
```

Comment: thanks i try your way to see result thanks for your help